# STM32 DMA transfer error

Tags: c, stm32, spi, dma

I use STM32F407VTG6 controller and try to receive data from SPI using DMA. Then I want to process data on DMA Complete Transfer Interrupt. But when Complete Transfer Interrupt is occurred I see that TEIF (transfer error interrupt flag) is set. After this DMA can't be started. This is part of my code:

```
static void DmaInit()
{
 DMA_InitTypeDef dma;

 RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);

 // DMA for Rx
 dma.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_3;
 dma.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&SPI1->DR;
 dma.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = 0; // will be set later
 dma.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
 dma.DMA_BufferSize = 1; // will be set later
 dma.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
 dma.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
 dma.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
 dma.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
 dma.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
 dma.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
 dma.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;
 dma.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
 dma.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
 dma.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
 DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream2);
 DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream2, &dma);

 // Enable DMA Interrupt on complete transfer
 NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn);
 DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream2, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
}

// It run on external interrupt
static void DmaStart(uint32_t bufferSize, uint32_t* rxBuffer)
{ 
 // Start DMA for reading
 DMA2_Stream2->NDTR = bufferSize;
 DMA2_Stream2->M0AR = (uint32_t)rxBuffer;
 DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream2, ENABLE);
}

static void SpiInit()
{
  SPI_InitTypeDef spi;

  // Enable clock for SPI
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);

  // SPI settings
  SPI_StructInit(&spi);
  spi.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
  spi.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
  spi.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
  spi.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
  spi.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
  spi.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
  spi.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_16;
  spi.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
  SPI_Init(SPI1, &spi);
  SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

  SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPI1, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Rx, ENABLE);
}
```

Comment: Just I hope that someone faced with same problem and he have solution of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just finished my SDIO+DMA this days, some notes maybe useful for you:

1. Clear Flags before enabling the stream

   ```
   DMA_ClearFlag(DMA2_Stream2, DMA_FLAG_FEIF2|DMA_FLAG_DMEIF2|DMA_FLAG_TEIF2|DMA_FLAG_HTIF2|DMA_FLAG_TCIF2);
   ```
2. Clear EN bit in the DMA_SxCR Register, Wait Until the EN bit is read as 0 before DMA_Init()

   ```
   DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream2, DISABLE);
   while (DMA2_Stream2->CR & DMA_SxCR_EN);
   ```
3. When use DMA_FIFOMode_Disable (Direct Mode), data width is determined by DMA_PeripheralDataSize (PSIZE), DMA_MemoryDataSize (MSIZE) is ignored
4. Memory address must be aligned to your selected data width (HalfWord)

Reference:

1. [STM32F407XX Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/cn/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf) - Chapter 10 DMA Controller
2. STM32F4XX Standard Peripheral Library

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Calling DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream2, DISABLE) before DmaInit solved this problem.